# No validation errors on sign in, present on sign up with Devise/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using Devise with Rails, but validating myself in the model to provide custom error messages:

```
validates :email,
    :uniqueness => {:message => :unique_email},
    :presence => {:message => :email_missing}
```

YML:

```
unique_email: "Email address needs to be unique"
email_missing: "Email address can't be blank"
```

View:

`=@user.errors.messages.inspect`

yields nothing, an empty object! Yet this all works fine on sign up...

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Ok, it's putting the login errors in like so:

```
- flash.each do |name, msg|
    .standalone_form--message= msg
```

So how can I customise these messages (ie. from a yml file)? Like I've done with the `@user.errors.messages`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your messages using [locales](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) as Rails guides recommends:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "Email address"
    errors:
       models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "can't be blank"
              unique: "should be unique"
```

---

**Note: Do not use the following, it's only to show the YAML issue**

That said, about your error, this should work:

```
validates :email,
  :uniqueness => {:message => "Email address should be unique"}
```

The problem is that you should load the YAML file properly:

Create a file named `config/error_messages.yaml`:

```
unique_email: "Email address needs to be unique"
email_missing: "Email address can't be blank"
```

Add a Ruby file `config/initializers/load_error_messages.rb`:

```
ERROR_MESSAGES = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config", "initializers", "config.yml"))
```

Then use it on the validation like this:

```
validates :email,
  :uniqueness => {:message => ERROR_MESSAGES['unique_email']}
```

( Source: [RailsCast #85](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file))